# PHP how to access key inside foreach function and then pass to mysql query

Tags: php, arrays

How to access array key inside foreach function and then pass to mysql query. The following code returns blank page. When the "key" is static id='2', there are no problems. But I need to use the array keys, instead of static values.

```
foreach ($base as $key => &$value) {
    $value = db_query("SELECT * FROM {bo_subject} WHERE exam LIKE '%$key%'")->fetchAllKeyed() or exit(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because poster can't be bothered to read basic PHP documentation


Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Beat me to it @MarkBaker :p

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    ...
}
```

(see [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php))

EDIT: Pass $value by reference

Comment: Than you for reply. It doesn't work in my case

foreach ($base as $key => $value) {
    $value = db_query("SELECT * FROM {bo_name} WHERE exam LIKE '%$key%'")->fetchAllKeyed() or exit(mysql_error());
}
I need to use foreach ($base as &$value)

Comment: Where's the problem using `foreach ($array as $key => &$value)`?

Comment: With foreach ($base as &$value) I can create add arrays to existing array http://prntscr.com/1tzrlc The problem is that do this with static $id for example id='4'

Comment: the problem is in this 
$value = db_query("SELECT * FROM {bo_subject} WHERE exam LIKE '%$key%'")->fetchAllKeyed() or exit(mysql_error()); When I do $value = $key; its ok.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using "&" ever, till You are really sure what You are doing. Also i propose to use "for" instead of "foreach" because is a bit faster, more predictable and it is "right" way to change array during loop (for that in most cases reference is used). For getting keys from current value use key() function. It's well documented on php.net manual.

Comment: When I changed the $id = key($base) I received:

http://prntscr.com/1tzu4g